# Cocos2D 2.0 - CCCallFuncN not working?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have this code:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:temp/10.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(verify)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];


CCMoveTo *moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:temp position:positionX];
id doneAction = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:timer selector:@selector(invalidate)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions: moveTo, doneAction, nil];
[self.container runAction:sequence];
```

the problem is that the timer is not invalidated and continues to run after the animation ends.

what am I missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CCCallFuncN` to `CCCallFunc`

```
id doneAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:timer selector:@selector(invalidate)];
```

CCCallFuncN looks for an object to pass into the function using `withObject:`.  You don't need this.